# Concat dataframes with same index returned from a for loop

Tags: python, dataframe

Hi I'm having for loop which returns a DataFrame. Each time for loop returns a dataFrame with same index and a same column name. How can I concat them all together to get a single dataframe?

Appreciate if a small example can be provided

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that your loop generates a dataframe `pd.DataFrame([[5, 6], [7, 8]] )` with columns "A" and "B" in each iteration. You can concat them with `append`.

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame([], columns=list('AB'))
for i in range(10):
    df2 = df2.append(pd.DataFrame([[5, 6], [7, 8]], columns=list('AB')), ignore_index=True)
```